# mongodb Insert of geo object generated a high number of keys

Tags: mongodb, key, 2dsphere

I have a lot "Insert of geo object generated a high number of keys" entries in my log file and not sure if this actually affects any performance or other things.
I'm aware of the reason, I have a pretty big table with 2dsphere indexes combined with a array.
e.g.:
location: 2dsphere
values: [String]

index{ 'location': '2dsphere', 'values': 1}

if "values" gets more entries, it has to combine all the entries. But why is there this log entry? Is it harmful to have a "big" index? (.. about 99% read only queries btw) in this case?

thanks
Simon